# Should Kotlin files be put in a separate source directory in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm going to start using Kotlin for Android development in addition to Java because of its benefits. I have installed the Android Studio plugin and included the relevant dependencies in my gradle files.

So I've read from the Kotlin documentation and Stack Overflow that it's possible to include a separate source directory for Kotlin files, like so:

> app:
>   -manifest
>   -java
>   **-kotlin**
>   -res

I know I can create this directory by adding the following to my `build.gradle` file:

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}
```

My question is: **should Kotlin files 'live' with Java files in the same directory or not?**

In addition to opinions, I would like to know whether there is a particular convention for this, and if so, why it is the way that it is.

If not, then what are the advantages and disadvantages of each option?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Putting the Kotlin files in a separate source directory exists as a documented possibility because in early (pre-1.0) versions of Kotlin this was the only supported setup. Afterwards, the Kotlin Gradle plugin was made more flexible, so the directory separation is no longer necessary. I'm not aware of any benefits that could be gained by putting Kotlin files in a separate source directory.

Having a separate source directory is especially inconvenient when you have a Java project which you're gradually converting to Kotlin. Moving each converted file to a different source directory makes the conversion process unnecessarily more cumbersome.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already have a fairly large Java project (for Android) which I am going to add Kotlin files to and convert a few Java files to Kotlin. I agree that moving each converted file will be tedious, and I imagine it would also be inconvenient to have to navigate through different directories to find a Kotlin file which would normally be under the same package as a Java file. At the moment, I'm favouring the option of keeping all files under one source directory, but is there a way to rename the `java` source directory to something more relevant.

Comment: You can use the same setup code as shown in your question to create a source root with the name that you prefer, and simply delete the "java" source root. However, if you're worried about conventions, I don't think such a setup would be conventional.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I'll keep using the `java` source directory for now, and perhaps when I have a large number of kotlin files, I'll move them to a separate source directory.

Answer (score 6):

Since the placement of files does not mean much to the Kotlin compiler, the convention is to place the in the modules "logically" the same way you would do with Java files.

For example, if you have decided to refactor a Java class by converting it into Kotlin, the resulting Kotlin file should take the place of the original Java file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to rename the `java` source directory, so it makes more sense, as it would contain not only java source files, but also kotlin source files?

Comment: That's more a Grade question that a Kotlin one. Personally I would not bothered to rename anything

Comment: getting a classnotfoundexception when trying to run an empty kotlin mainactivity?